# Ordered list where items don‘t know each other and sorted by attribute in the Cloud: How to avoid index changes in Cloud when user reorders?

Tags: swift, algorithm

I'm (for example) working with `sortDescriptor` inside a `NSFetchedResultsController`.
When I move an item from once place to another I do not want to change every record in-between.

#### Example

```
a.index=0 b.index=1 c.index=2
# Moving c to the front requires three index changes:
c.index=0 a.index=1 b.index=2
```

Comment: Just call insert row delegate and `tableView.beginUpdates`, `tableView.endUpdates` after changing the data source.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri How does that help with not having to update sortIndexes to the right of the newly-inserted item?

Comment: Doesn’t swift already do that in the insert method?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Yes Collection implements insert. The point is all objects live in the cloud and the user can move items around in the collection. The list is ordered by sortKey, so moving around changes the sortKey, so Collection doesn‘t help cause collection doesn‘t sort the items, `sortKey` does.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1: Gaps between ints

```
a.index=0 b.index=10 c.index=20
# Moving c to the front requires 1 index change
c.index=-10 a.index=0 b.index=10
```

Its downside is that it still requires thought incase items may be inserted between two often enough.

Biggest gap worst case: Always between two.

```
func int64Test() {
    let a: Int64 = 0
    var b: Int64 = Int64.max

    var i = 0
    while a != b {
        print("i:", i, "a:", a, "b:", b, "diff:", b-a)
        //        b = (b - a) / 2.0 + a
        b = (b + a) / 2
        i = i + 1
    }
}

i: 0 a: 0 b: 9223372036854775807 diff: 9223372036854775807
i: 1 a: 0 b: 4611686018427387903 diff: 4611686018427387903
i: 2 a: 0 b: 2305843009213693951 diff: 2305843009213693951
i: 3 a: 0 b: 1152921504606846975 diff: 1152921504606846975
i: 4 a: 0 b: 576460752303423487 diff: 576460752303423487
i: 5 a: 0 b: 288230376151711743 diff: 288230376151711743
i: 6 a: 0 b: 144115188075855871 diff: 144115188075855871
i: 7 a: 0 b: 72057594037927935 diff: 72057594037927935
i: 8 a: 0 b: 36028797018963967 diff: 36028797018963967
i: 9 a: 0 b: 18014398509481983 diff: 18014398509481983
i: 10 a: 0 b: 9007199254740991 diff: 9007199254740991
i: 11 a: 0 b: 4503599627370495 diff: 4503599627370495
i: 12 a: 0 b: 2251799813685247 diff: 2251799813685247
i: 13 a: 0 b: 1125899906842623 diff: 1125899906842623
i: 14 a: 0 b: 562949953421311 diff: 562949953421311
i: 15 a: 0 b: 281474976710655 diff: 281474976710655
i: 16 a: 0 b: 140737488355327 diff: 140737488355327
i: 17 a: 0 b: 70368744177663 diff: 70368744177663
i: 18 a: 0 b: 35184372088831 diff: 35184372088831
i: 19 a: 0 b: 17592186044415 diff: 17592186044415
i: 20 a: 0 b: 8796093022207 diff: 8796093022207
i: 21 a: 0 b: 4398046511103 diff: 4398046511103
i: 22 a: 0 b: 2199023255551 diff: 2199023255551
i: 23 a: 0 b: 1099511627775 diff: 1099511627775
i: 24 a: 0 b: 549755813887 diff: 549755813887
i: 25 a: 0 b: 274877906943 diff: 274877906943
i: 26 a: 0 b: 137438953471 diff: 137438953471
i: 27 a: 0 b: 68719476735 diff: 68719476735
i: 28 a: 0 b: 34359738367 diff: 34359738367
i: 29 a: 0 b: 17179869183 diff: 17179869183
i: 30 a: 0 b: 8589934591 diff: 8589934591
i: 31 a: 0 b: 4294967295 diff: 4294967295
i: 32 a: 0 b: 2147483647 diff: 2147483647
i: 33 a: 0 b: 1073741823 diff: 1073741823
i: 34 a: 0 b: 536870911 diff: 536870911
i: 35 a: 0 b: 268435455 diff: 268435455
i: 36 a: 0 b: 134217727 diff: 134217727
i: 37 a: 0 b: 67108863 diff: 67108863
i: 38 a: 0 b: 33554431 diff: 33554431
i: 39 a: 0 b: 16777215 diff: 16777215
i: 40 a: 0 b: 8388607 diff: 8388607
i: 41 a: 0 b: 4194303 diff: 4194303
i: 42 a: 0 b: 2097151 diff: 2097151
i: 43 a: 0 b: 1048575 diff: 1048575
i: 44 a: 0 b: 524287 diff: 524287
i: 45 a: 0 b: 262143 diff: 262143
i: 46 a: 0 b: 131071 diff: 131071
i: 47 a: 0 b: 65535 diff: 65535
i: 48 a: 0 b: 32767 diff: 32767
i: 49 a: 0 b: 16383 diff: 16383
i: 50 a: 0 b: 8191 diff: 8191
i: 51 a: 0 b: 4095 diff: 4095
i: 52 a: 0 b: 2047 diff: 2047
i: 53 a: 0 b: 1023 diff: 1023
i: 54 a: 0 b: 511 diff: 511
i: 55 a: 0 b: 255 diff: 255
i: 56 a: 0 b: 127 diff: 127
i: 57 a: 0 b: 63 diff: 63
i: 58 a: 0 b: 31 diff: 31
i: 59 a: 0 b: 15 diff: 15
i: 60 a: 0 b: 7 diff: 7
i: 61 a: 0 b: 3 diff: 3
i: 62 a: 0 b: 1 diff: 1
```

#### Option 2: Strings and length

```
a.index=c b.index=f c.index=i
# Moving c to the front requires 1 index change
c.index=a a.index=c b.index=f
```

Since there's no negative this is more inconvenient, but strings are only limited by memory and so may have advantages over #1.

#### Option 3: Double

```
a.index=5 b.index=10 c.index=15
# Moving c to the front requires 1 index change
c.index=7.5 a.index=5 b.index=10
```

Double has limits on accuracy though, so not perfect either.

```
func doubleTest() {
    let a: Double = 1
    var b: Double = 2

    var i = 0
    while a != b {
        print("i:", i, "a:", a, "b:", b, "diff:", b-a)
        //        b = (b - a) / 2.0 + a
        b = (b + a) / 2
        i = i + 1
    }
}

i: 0 a: 1.0 b: 2.0 diff: 1.0
i: 1 a: 1.0 b: 1.5 diff: 0.5
i: 2 a: 1.0 b: 1.25 diff: 0.25
i: 3 a: 1.0 b: 1.125 diff: 0.125
i: 4 a: 1.0 b: 1.0625 diff: 0.0625
i: 5 a: 1.0 b: 1.03125 diff: 0.03125
i: 6 a: 1.0 b: 1.015625 diff: 0.015625
i: 7 a: 1.0 b: 1.0078125 diff: 0.0078125
i: 8 a: 1.0 b: 1.00390625 diff: 0.00390625
i: 9 a: 1.0 b: 1.001953125 diff: 0.001953125
i: 10 a: 1.0 b: 1.0009765625 diff: 0.0009765625
i: 11 a: 1.0 b: 1.00048828125 diff: 0.00048828125
i: 12 a: 1.0 b: 1.000244140625 diff: 0.000244140625
i: 13 a: 1.0 b: 1.0001220703125 diff: 0.0001220703125
i: 14 a: 1.0 b: 1.00006103515625 diff: 6.103515625e-05
i: 15 a: 1.0 b: 1.000030517578125 diff: 3.0517578125e-05
i: 16 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000152587890625 diff: 1.52587890625e-05
i: 17 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000076293945312 diff: 7.62939453125e-06
i: 18 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000038146972656 diff: 3.814697265625e-06
i: 19 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000019073486328 diff: 1.9073486328125e-06
i: 20 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000009536743164 diff: 9.5367431640625e-07
i: 21 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000004768371582 diff: 4.76837158203125e-07
i: 22 a: 1.0 b: 1.000000238418579 diff: 2.384185791015625e-07
i: 23 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000001192092896 diff: 1.1920928955078125e-07
i: 24 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000596046448 diff: 5.960464477539063e-08
i: 25 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000298023224 diff: 2.9802322387695312e-08
i: 26 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000149011612 diff: 1.4901161193847656e-08
i: 27 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000074505806 diff: 7.450580596923828e-09
i: 28 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000037252903 diff: 3.725290298461914e-09
i: 29 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000018626451 diff: 1.862645149230957e-09
i: 30 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000009313226 diff: 9.313225746154785e-10
i: 31 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000004656613 diff: 4.656612873077393e-10
i: 32 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000002328306 diff: 2.3283064365386963e-10
i: 33 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000001164153 diff: 1.1641532182693481e-10
i: 34 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000000582077 diff: 5.820766091346741e-11
i: 35 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000000291038 diff: 2.9103830456733704e-11
i: 36 a: 1.0 b: 1.000000000014552 diff: 1.4551915228366852e-11
i: 37 a: 1.0 b: 1.000000000007276 diff: 7.275957614183426e-12
i: 38 a: 1.0 b: 1.000000000003638 diff: 3.637978807091713e-12
i: 39 a: 1.0 b: 1.000000000001819 diff: 1.8189894035458565e-12
i: 40 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000000009095 diff: 9.094947017729282e-13
i: 41 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000000004547 diff: 4.547473508864641e-13
i: 42 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000000002274 diff: 2.2737367544323206e-13
i: 43 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000000001137 diff: 1.1368683772161603e-13
i: 44 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000000000568 diff: 5.684341886080802e-14
i: 45 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000000000284 diff: 2.842170943040401e-14
i: 46 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000000000142 diff: 1.4210854715202004e-14
i: 47 a: 1.0 b: 1.000000000000007 diff: 7.105427357601002e-15
i: 48 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000000000036 diff: 3.552713678800501e-15
i: 49 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000000000018 diff: 1.7763568394002505e-15
i: 50 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000000000009 diff: 8.881784197001252e-16
i: 51 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000000000004 diff: 4.440892098500626e-16
i: 52 a: 1.0 b: 1.0000000000000002 diff: 2.220446049250313e-16
```

#### Option 4: BigDouble